# SPARQL query to get the parent class and then find relations of the parent class to a third class and find annotations of the third class

Tags: python, sparql, owl, ontology

I am new to the field of Ontologies, trying to build something in Protégé. I have a sample structure which looks something like this:

[image]

The idea is that if I query for Salami - it should goto its parent class "Swine" and check if Swine has any properties for relations with any specific spendcategory. If there is a property - in my case I have a property "isRelatedTo" which connects Swine to Pork. I want to retrieve the annotation "spendcategory" from "Pork".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:trial-sparql="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Annotation properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLAnnotationProperty_ea40c8b6_5f54_4d6a_b186_1fdd794ccd64 -->

<owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLAnnotationProperty_ea40c8b6_5f54_4d6a_b186_1fdd794ccd64">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">SpendCategory</rdfs:label>
</owl:AnnotationProperty>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLObjectProperty_d75c5f32_6c22_44f9_9707_1a1a640aa013 -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLObjectProperty_d75c5f32_6c22_44f9_9707_1a1a640aa013">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">isRelatedto</rdfs:label>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_41cec2ba_48bc_423e_b8dd_1c24d4db3f43 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_41cec2ba_48bc_423e_b8dd_1c24d4db3f43">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">SpendCategory</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_41dcbdc3_93af_4f15_bd7e_0388bc117a7a -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_41dcbdc3_93af_4f15_bd7e_0388bc117a7a">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_adf820bb_7f9c_4e40_b1fd_014278cb9d4c"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">sausage</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_4b569d99_c827_42d4_a22a_65bfb5f64ffc -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_4b569d99_c827_42d4_a22a_65bfb5f64ffc">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_41cec2ba_48bc_423e_b8dd_1c24d4db3f43"/>
    <OWLAnnotationProperty_ea40c8b6_5f54_4d6a_b186_1fdd794ccd64>R123400000</OWLAnnotationProperty_ea40c8b6_5f54_4d6a_b186_1fdd794ccd64>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Pork</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_5d60365c_44fa_4870_a8ed_eea94ff99728 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_5d60365c_44fa_4870_a8ed_eea94ff99728">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_adf820bb_7f9c_4e40_b1fd_014278cb9d4c"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">salami</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_adf820bb_7f9c_4e40_b1fd_014278cb9d4c -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_adf820bb_7f9c_4e40_b1fd_014278cb9d4c">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLObjectProperty_d75c5f32_6c22_44f9_9707_1a1a640aa013"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rdkarkhasa/ontologies/2021/9/trial-sparql#OWLClass_4b569d99_c827_42d4_a22a_65bfb5f64ffc"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Swine</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to do this in Python. I tried building upon the query, but not able to understand how to get something in my case get the parent class of salami - ie. Swine and then search for the properties that Swine would have and then get the annotations of Pork. How to do this linking? any pointers to read are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve and it is therefore very hard to give an answer. You say something about "go to a parent class" and find any properties. But properties are typically used to connect individuals. So do you want to ...

1. ... query information on class / property level? In your case this is not possible as you have no detailed information e.g. about domain or range of your properties.
2. ... query the actual data, i.e., individuals of the classes and their relations to other individuals? Your ontology doesn't contain any individuals so there's not much to query.

If you want to achieve (1) you need more details, e.g., you need the explicit information that `isRelatedTo` connects individuals of class `Swine` with individuals of class `Pork` and that your annotation is applied to individuals of class `Pork`.

And if you want to achieve (2), you first need data, i.e., individuals of your classes and relations between them. And furthermore, you should rephrase your question. If you want to query for a specific class (`Salami`) and trace the relation `isRelatedTo` of all the salamis in your model, there is no need to "go to the parent class", because you are already querying for specific individuals which are related via `isRelatedTo` to some pork individual.

I dont't want to sound harsh, but I would recommend to get more familiar with the fundamentals of ontologies by some basic books like ["Semantic Web for the Working Ontologist: Effective Modeling for Linked Data, RDFS, and OWL"](https://doi.org/10.1145/3382097).
If you like something even more "hands-on", I recommend the [official Protege tutorial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3Y8T6nIfXQ_UQOpCAr_HFSCwpTqELeP/view) in its latest version.